# tensorflow object detection API train.py self error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection

I have ran through all the installation steps for the tensorflow object detection API. I have checked several guides on proper installation just to really make sure I did it correctly. However I still receive this error again and again:

```html
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.create_global_step
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 183, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "train.py", line 179, in main
    graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
  File "/xxxx/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py", line 262, in train
    global_step = slim.create_global_step()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 250, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/variables.py", line 135, in create_global_step
    return training_util.create_global_step(graph)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/training_util.py", line 143, in create_global_step
    ops.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_STEP])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1297, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1093, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 439, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 408, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource, constraint=constraint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 800, in _get_single_variable
    use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 2157, in variable
    use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 2147, in <lambda>
    previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 2130, in default_variable_creator
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 235, in __init__
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 337, in _init_from_args
    initial_value(), name="initial_value", dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 784, in <lambda>
    shape.as_list(), dtype=dtype, partition_info=partition_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py", line 99, in __call__
    return array_ops.zeros(shape, dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1601, in zeros
    output = fill(shape, constant(zero, dtype=dtype), name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 214, in constant
    value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 533, in make_tensor_proto
    append_fn(tensor_proto, proto_values)
  File "tensorflow/python/framework/fast_tensor_util.pyx", line 45, in tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util.AppendInt64ArrayToTensorProto
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/containers.py", line 251, in append
    self._values.append(self._type_checker.CheckValue(value))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'self' referenced before assignment
```

I am using a VERY small training set (15 images), just to get a handle on the entire process - of course I will add more later for accuracy. I mention this however in case it is relevant.

I suspected something was incorrect with either the config file, the train.py file itself (with respect to my dataset), or the .record files. However to me everything seems to be in line.

I am utilizing the ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017 dataset and ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets config.

Any tips are really appreciated. Please let me know if I left out necessary details.

Comment: It looks like a possible path issue in your .config file.

Comment: i have checked the paths many times. quite frustrating. i have tried an absolute and relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with python version 3.7(MacOS 10.13.4), I have rechecked the path given in `.config` file but it was the correct one. I could solve the problem by downgrading python to version2.7 and followed the same installation steps in tensorflow object recognition and search for `schedule` in `.config` file and remove below block.

`schedule {
            step: 0
            learning_rate: .0001
          }`

Then run,

`python legacy/train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config`

This may be due to version mismatch.